# Change datagrid cell color based on value and column header name

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am using a datagrid populated from a sql db.  It is written in c# and xaml. I wrote a converter to change the color of a cell based on the data in one of my columns. This works but the problem is that it iterates through all cells in my datagrid and changes the color of each cell regardless of what column it is in.  I want to check the value of the cell and only change its color if it is in a certain column. Is there a way to pass the column name and the value of the cell to my converter?

Thanks

Comment: You can use a DataTemplateSelector and then style particular column as you did

Comment: Post relevant code here.

Comment: Thanks will this work even if I am using AutoGenerateColumns="True"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataTemplateSelector in WPF.

A sample can be found here.

http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2010/08/23/apply-conditional-data-template-in-data-grid/